# Injecting in Django for testing and debugging

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I am writing an app which depends heavily on dates and times. I want to be able to have an injectable concept of `now()` and `today()`. I was thinking that I could write my own versions of these two functions which would check some central setting, to which I will refer to as `INJECTED_NOW`. If `INJECTED_NOW` is None, the above functions would just return the values of `datetime.datetime.now()` and `datetime.date.today()`.  However, if `INJECTED_NOW` has a datetime value, the above functions would use it to get now() and today().

I am wondering how I could store INJECTED_NOW so that it is mutable. I would like to be able to set it at the beginning of a test case and modify it before another test case. Similarly, I would like to be able to set it from the request, perhaps using middleware.

Does this approach make sense, and if so, how should I store INJECTED_NOW? I would like to avoid a DB access. Is there an alternate way of addressing this problem?

Comment: take a look at this library http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/ it is really easy and usefull for cases like yours

Comment: I am aware of mock, but I am not sure how I would override the built-in datetime.date.today() or the datetime.datetime.now() functions with it.

Answer (score 4):

There's a recently released library called FreezeGun that lets specify datetimes like you describe:

http://stevepulec.com/freezegun/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it using mock, for more information about mock see the [docs](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/getting-started.html)

```py
# this should be the code your are testing
import datetime

def one_minute_ago():
    return (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)).time()


# this would be in your tests file
import mock
import sys
import unittest

class SomeTestcase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one_minute_ago(self):
        real_datetime = datetime.datetime
        fake_now = datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 21, 11, 13, 13)
        with mock.patch('datetime.datetime', spec=datetime.datetime) as datetime_mock:
            datetime_mock.now.return_value = fake_now

            self.assertEqual(one_minute_ago(), datetime.time(11, 12, 13))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(unittest.main())
```

To test it just copy the code to a file and run it with Python.